# How to print JSON data dynamically to multiple columns of CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am very new to Python, I am trying to scrape a website navigation menu and trying to store that data in a CSV file. The script is working fine and I am able store the data in CSV. The only issue I am facing is that I am unable to store those data to multiple columns. The data is saved in the first column of the CSV file.

Here is my code:

```
import csv, json, sys
import bs4, requests


def to_dict(r):
   if all(isinstance(i, dict) for i in r):
      return {a:b for i in r for a, b in i.items()}
   if all(isinstance(i, list) for i in r):
      return [i for b in r for i in b]
   return r

def get_menu(page_name):
   if page_name.name == 'li':
      #collect all li values, create a dictionary if li has a ul child
      li_text = []
      for i in page_name.contents:
         if isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString) or i.select_one('ul') is None:
           if (t:=i.get_text(strip=True)): #default li text
              li_text.append(t)
         else: #li contains a ul, build a dict with li's text as key
            if li_text:
               li_text.append({li_text.pop():to_dict([*get_menu(i)])})
               
            else:
               yield to_dict([*get_menu(i)])
      yield from li_text
      return
   all_text = []
   for i in page_name.contents:
      if getattr(i, 'name', None) == 'ul':
         r = [*get_menu(i)] #get ul's li values
         e, flag = i, False
         while (e:=e.previous_sibling) is not None: #check if ul has descriptive text
           if (isinstance(e, bs4.element.NavigableString) or e.select_one('ul') is None) and e.get_text(strip=True):
              yield {e.get_text(strip=True):to_dict(r)} #yield back dictionary if text exists
              flag = True
              break
         if not flag: yield to_dict(r)
      elif not isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString):
         yield from get_menu(i) #recursively traverse element

def menu_items(link):
   page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, 'html.parser')
   for nav in page.select('nav'): #find all `nav` elements from which to anchor search
      yield to_dict([*get_menu(nav)])
     



for i in menu_items('https://www.turramusic.com.au/'):
   
   f = csv.writer(open(r"C:\Users\Manikanta-WD\Desktop\run\csv\url_output.csv", "w"))
   f.writerow(["level 1", "level 2", "level 3", "level 4", "level 5"])
   for x in i:
    f.writerow([x])
```

Here is an image of the output:

[image: output CSV image]

But i want to print different levels of the menu to different columns of the sheet. Is it possible?

I tried some code like this:

```
for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["Keyboards & Synths"],
                x["Drums & Percussion"],
                x["fields"]["Band & Orchestral'"],
                x["fields"]["Live Sound"],
                x["fields"]["Amps & Effects"]])
```

This is not working and I know this not a dynamic way to print it. Is there any way I can make this dynamic like first level in one column and second level in the next column etc?

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: CSV is for data with a fixed number of columns. Making the output JSON instead would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Also, you’re looping over menu items and (over)writing them all to the same file… the same CSV file for multiple different items. Did you mean to write to different files for different items?